# Change locale setting in Yocto

Tags: python-3.x, locale, yocto, bitbake

[This is the error occur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNNL5.png)

I get the error as show in figure due to the default locale setting in Yocto is POSIX. Now my problem is that I have no idea how to change the locale setting to en_US.utf-8 in Yocto

Comment: Which Operating system do you use?

Comment: Please share more details, like the full and exact error message and your debugging attempts

Answer (score 3):

I am also using yocto. I got an error like the following when trying to run a script on python3.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     ...
>   RuntimeError: Click will abort further execution because Python 3 was
>     configured to use ASCII as encoding for the environment. Either switch
>     to Python 2 or consult http://click.pocoo.org/python3/ for
>     mitigation steps.

To solve it, first I had to enable UTF-8 in your local.conf

```
GLIBC_GENERATE_LOCALES = "en_GB.UTF-8 en_US.UTF-8"
```

then, when running locale -a on the target I got something like.

```
C
en_GB
en_US
POSIX
```

To make sure the locals are UTF-8, I used the c program from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42784435/how-to-check-if-a-locale-is-utf-8/42797421#42797421) and  got something like:

```
C ->ANSI_X3.4-1968
en_GB ->UTF-8
en_US ->UTF-8
POSIX ->ANSI_X3.4-1968
```

Finally

```
export LC_ALL=en_US
export LANG=en_US
```

After that, I had no errors about locals. Hope that help any of you.

Answer (score 1):

You could use profile.d and write a recipe as follows:

```
DESCRIPTION = "Copy scripts to profile.d"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"
SRC_URI = "file://*"

GLIBC_GENERATE_LOCALES="en_GB.UTF-8 en_US.UTF-8"
IMAGE_LINGUAS = "en-us"

RDEPENDS_${PN} = "bash"

do_install () {
        install -d ${D}/etc/profile.d
        install -m755 ${WORKDIR}/lang.sh ${D}/etc/profile.d
}
```

you need a subfolder where the shell script is located, name doesnt matter, because the line:

```
SRC_URI = "file://*"
```

sources the subfolder.

The shell script `lang.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Place the shell script in that subfolder and add the name of the recipe to your image target :)