# pip mangles password for proxy

Tags: linux, encoding, pip, proxy, iso-8859-1

I am trying to install python packages on an embedded device with some form of yocto linux. I managed to connect this device to the proxy at work. After setting http[s]_proxy accordingly, `wget http://www.google.de` works and downloads googles landing page. However, pip still does not comply.

Executing `pip3 install seaborn` yields

```
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 188, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 345, in run
    resolver.resolve(requirement_set)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/legacy_resolve.py", line 196, in resolve
    self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/legacy_resolve.py", line 359, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/legacy_resolve.py", line 307, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    self.require_hashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 134, in prepare_linked_requirement
    req.populate_link(finder, upgrade_allowed, require_hashes)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 211, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/index.py", line 1201, in find_requirement
    req.name, specifier=req.specifier, hashes=hashes,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/index.py", line 1183, in find_candidates
    candidates = self.find_all_candidates(project_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/index.py", line 1128, in find_all_candidates
    for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/index.py", line 1282, in _get_pages
    page = _get_html_page(location, session=self.session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/index.py", line 234, in _get_html_page
    resp = _get_html_response(url, session=session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/index.py", line 182, in _get_html_response
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=0",
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 546, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/download.py", line 624, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 53, in send
    resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 412, in send
    conn = self.get_connection(request.url, proxies)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 309, in get_connection
    proxy_manager = self.proxy_manager_for(proxy)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 192, in proxy_manager_for
    proxy_headers = self.proxy_headers(proxy)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 390, in proxy_headers
    password)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/auth.py", line 63, in _basic_auth_str
    password = password.encode('latin1')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\ufffd' in position 5: ordinal not in range(256)
```

I read from that, that somehow the replacement character \ufffd is inserted into my password. My password, as set into http_proxy does not contain non-ascii characters. The most "exotic" symbol is a percent sign "%".

More Details:

- pip3 version 19.2.3
- python version 3.7
- `http[s]_proxy=http[s]://[user]:[pass]@[proxy_url]:[proxy_port]`

Using the `--proxy` option from pip does not help the problem.

How can I bypass this?

Comment: Have you considered using `de_DE.UTF-8` instead of a mismatched `iso-8858-1` and `latin-1`?

Comment: @tink where would I need to change that?

Comment: Current `pip` version is `23.0.1` - update as soon as posiible.

Comment: @RobertBock - that will depend on your distro

Comment: @tink oh I just noticed, that in one of my early edits I removed the statement about the yocto image without any package management or gcc. Well a quick google search showed that the is a LANG environment variable? I guess I will try that tomorrow.

Comment: @JosefZ Yes, I know. Unfortunately `pip install --upgrade pip` also requires a connection to pypi. I will, however, not update, if I can avoid it, since the device is usually not connected to the internet and a lot of people depend on it working. So I won't make any chances to pip.

Comment: @RobertBock. hilft [das](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42090237/change-locale-setting-in-yocto/51296151#51296151)? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Special characters have to be **percent / url encoded**.

After trying for two hours I finally found a solution.
The hint came from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37219624/10375236).

In the provided ini they separated the domain via the url encoding `%5C` instead of an actual `/`.
Also they explain that special characters have to be percent encoded for pip.

This was the core error - pip decodes the password as part of the url and trips, because the `%` is not followed by a valid hex value.

Also just passing `--proxy` was not enough. `pip` tries to open subsequent HTTPS connections without that proxy argument for whatever reason, making it impossible to reach `pypi.org`. Therefore, you have to set your env variables `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` accordingly or possibly set the proxy in `pip.ini` as explained in the post mentioned above. Remember to use percent encoded special characters, if they are necessary.

Since our proxy setup is a bit scuffed anyway, I installed with
`pip3 install --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host pypi.python.org -vv [package]`
to avoid any more mishaps with SSL / TLS handshaking.

PS: Thanks @tink for your help. Unfortunately this yocto build had no `locale` and changing `LANG` to anything like `de_DE`, `de_DE.UTF8` or `en_US.UTF8` just completely stopped pip from parsing anything.